Prisoner gets crime victim pen-pal - science-fictional twist
A 21st-century Analog short story, I think. A near-future mugger (I think) is imprisoned, and as part of a rehabilitation program is given certain privileges if he becomes a pen-pal with a crime victim. He communicates with her over a long period, learning about the effect of the crime that she experienced on her life (I believe she was an elderly woman), and gradually the criminal learns empathy with all crime victims, including his own.  The reader learns that the letters were a product of a computer, generalizing from real victim experiences, and focusing the interactions to build an emotional bond between the real criminal and the fictional victim - I think this was a pilot program (which since successful in this case, will go into general use).

Not 21st century since I read it in Analog and it was before then.  The criminal is kept solitary to make him desperate to maintain contact, and I believe it's by voice, not pen pal.

Thanks.  Must have read it in an older issue, while I was in the 21st century myself.

Voice interaction does sound right now that you mention it.
